# Failures in the Docker daemon

Tags: docker, docker-compose, daemon

I am using docker in Windows 10 pro, which presents me with many problems (I consider switching to linux soon), but my problem originated since I uninstalled docker and reinstalled it, I downloaded the project in which I work and I realized that when I made any change and saved, it did not refresh the image and it did not render the changes, whatever it was even a console.log, I need to stop the container and do a docker-compose, has someone the same thing happened to him that can help me?

```
UPDATE
```

Checking the Volumes part in visualstudio, there is one which is a JSON and has this inside.

```
    {
  "CreatedAt": "2020-10-27T17:52:22Z",
  "Driver": "local",
  "Labels": null,
  "Mountpoint": "/var/lib/docker/volumes/015969819adff3cea9612ff2ea5eeed61a5f092dcec2c5777e2d96127cdc258a/_data",
  "Name": "015969819adff3cea9612ff2ea5eeed61a5f092dcec2c5777e2d96127cdc258a",
  "Options": null,
  "Scope": "local",
  "CreatedTime": 1603821142000
}
```

Is there any property missing?

Docker-compose

```
mobile:
build:
  context: ./mobile
  dockerfile: Dockerfile.dev
env_file:
  - .env
ports:
  - "8080:3000"
volumes:
  - ./mobile/src:/src
  - ./mobile/public:/public
  - ./mobile/config-overrides.js:/config-overrides.js
  - ./mobile/package.json:/package.json
  - ./mobile/docker:/docker
restart: always
```

Comment: Are you sure that your project is mounted as a volume on your container so that you can see live changes?

Comment: How can you verify that? Basically it is my work project, it works for all my colleagues, except me, which stopped working after installing Docker again

Comment: I just did an update, with what I get in my volumes

Comment: If you can share your docker-compose file instead or at least the relevant part, it would be easier to help.

Comment: I just did update with that

Comment: From what you described, it seems like it could be related to the way the volume containing your code is mounted. You can try either the `delegated` or `cached` method like so: `./mobile/src:/src:delegated` (assuming ./mobile/src is where you make changes) and see if it makes any difference.